# How to make variables available in routes and templates at the same time in node express?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I created an ssr node expressjs app with some client adjustable settings that are stored in a database. Examples are `enable_feature_x='y'` and `url_logo='https://domain.tld/logo.png'`.

Currently I load the variables in `app.js`, then I store them in `app.locals` and access them in the templates. But I somehow can't access them in routes. How can I access the `app` from within the routes?

I would like to be able to set them globally from `app.js` (on startup) and from an imported route (on update), and read them globally in any route and template.

I am sure this is a common problem, but I haven't found a solution yet. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access app object by `req.app` in express router.